# iOS app crashes when trying to "Sign in with Apple" using Firebase Authentication

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

I've got an issue with the Firebase Authentication for iOS. Specifically the "Sign in with Apple" Service. I've set up Firebase Authentication to work with my iOS application, but whenever I press the "Sign in with Apple" button, it first prompts me with the login window, which is good, but after it's completed, my app crashes. I've analyzed the crash log, but because of my lack of experience with these kinds of things, I was only able to figure out this much:

- When I press the "Sign in with Apple" button, my app first communicates with apple, creates the necessary nonce, and everything else. (LoginView.swift: 68 - 71)
- When that's done, it tries to send the data to firebase and log in there with the newly gotten credentials. (LoginView.swift: 90 - 91)
- But for some reason when this line of code gets executed, somewhere inside my app the **abort()** function is called, causing my entire app to terminate. (Crash report line 32)

My project is written in SwiftUI which is why I had some trouble implementing the authentication system because Firebase sadly only provided documentation for Swift UIKit. For that reason, I had to scramble the internet to find some code that should work and I'm not 100% sure that all my code is error-free and how it is supposed to be. But I've added the *GoogleService-Info.plist* file to my project and also to all build targets. I've installed Firebase using CocoaPods.

I've attached the important swift file as well as the crash report and my Podfile.

LoginView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI
import CryptoKit
import AuthenticationServices
import FirebaseAuth

struct LoginView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userAuth: UserAuth
    @State var currentNonce: String?
    
    private func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
      precondition(length > 0)
      let charset: [Character] =
        Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._")
      var result = ""
      var remainingLength = length

      while remainingLength > 0 {
        let randoms: [UInt8] = (0 ..< 16).map { _ in
          var random: UInt8 = 0
          let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, &random)
          if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
            fatalError(
              "Unable to generate nonce. SecRandomCopyBytes failed with OSStatus \(errorCode)"
            )
          }
          return random
        }

        randoms.forEach { random in
          if remainingLength == 0 {
            return
          }

          if random < charset.count {
            result.append(charset[Int(random)])
            remainingLength -= 1
          }
        }
      }

      return result
    }

    private func sha256(_ input: String) -> String {
      let inputData = Data(input.utf8)
      let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
      let hashString = hashedData.compactMap {
        String(format: "%02x", $0)
      }.joined()

      return hashString
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Login:")
            Spacer()
            SignInWithAppleButton(
                onRequest: { request in
                    let nonce = randomNonceString()
                    currentNonce = nonce
                    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
                    request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
                },
                onCompletion: { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let authResults):
                        switch authResults.credential {
                        case let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:
                            
                            guard let nonce = currentNonce else {
                                fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                            }
                            guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
                                fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                            }
                            guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
                                print("Unable to serialize token string from data: \(appleIDToken.debugDescription)")
                                return
                            }
                            
                            let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com",idToken: idTokenString,rawNonce: nonce)
                            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
                                if (error != nil) {
                                    // Error. If error.code == .MissingOrInvalidNonce, make sure
                                    // you're sending the SHA256-hashed nonce as a hex string with
                                    // your request to Apple.
                                    print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
                                    return
                                }
                                print("signed in")
                                self.userAuth.login()
                            }
                            
                            print("\(String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid))")
                        default:
                            break
                            
                        }
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                })
            .frame(height: 30)
            .padding(.horizontal, 80)
            .padding(.vertical, 100)
        }
    }
}

struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

Crash Report:

```
Incident Identifier: 93DC9180-3E51-4D61-ADEA-3A43FEC12A2E
Hardware Model:      iPhone12,1
Process:             Formatio [6512]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0147F52-1465-4998-A6F3-F0487C71B14F/Formatio.app/Formatio
Identifier:          ****
Version:             1.3 (11)
AppStoreTools:       13F100
AppVariant:          1:iPhone12,1:15
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           ****

Date/Time:           2022-08-31 19:31:14.0972 +0200
Launch Time:         2022-08-31 19:31:07.7006 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.6 (19G71)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    3.04.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1a7839288 __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:200)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1c0568744 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1a7890390 +[NSException raise:format:] + 112 (NSException.m:156)
3   FirebaseAuth                    0x1048ebac8 +[FIRAuth auth] + 92 (FIRAuth.m:442)
4   Formatio                        0x1046195dc closure #2 in closure #1 in LoginView.body.getter + 492 (LoginView.swift:91)
5   _AuthenticationServices_SwiftUI 0x21cf91ce0 @objc Coordinator.authorizationController(controller:didCompleteWithAuthorization:) + 104 (SignInWithAppleButton.swift:320)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a749ee6c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1517)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a74a0a30 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a74aef48 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928 (inline_internal.h:2622)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a74aeb98 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44 (queue.c:7770)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x1a77f1800 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1795)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x1a77ab704 __CFRunLoopRun + 2532 (CFRunLoop.c:3144)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x1a77bebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
13  GraphicsServices                0x1c3929374 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
14  UIKitCore                       0x1aa132b58 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3511)
15  UIKitCore                       0x1a9eb4090 UIApplicationMain + 364 (UIApplication.m:5064)
16  SwiftUI                         0x1af618f24 closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 164 (UIKitApp.swift:35)
17  SwiftUI                         0x1af546e08 runApp<A>(_:) + 252 (<compiler-generated>:0)
18  SwiftUI                         0x1af5280f4 static App.main() + 128 (App.swift:114)
19  Formatio                        0x10456f66c $main + 24 (<compiler-generated>:10)
20  Formatio                        0x10456f66c main + 36 (PopupView.swift:0)
21  dyld                            0x104b2dda4 start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:879)

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001df2dbb38 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002189ff3bc pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1668)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b294b524 abort + 168 (abort.c:118)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001c0673b7c abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:78)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001c06639c4 demangling_terminate_handler() + 336 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:71)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c056ec68 _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001c0672f18 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001c0672eb4 std::terminate() + 64 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a74a0a44 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:563)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a74aef48 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928 (inline_internal.h:2622)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a74aeb98 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44 (queue.c:7770)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a77f1800 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1795)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a77ab704 __CFRunLoopRun + 2532 (CFRunLoop.c:3144)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a77bebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
14  GraphicsServices                0x00000001c3929374 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200)
15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aa132b58 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3511)
16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a9eb4090 UIApplicationMain + 364 (UIApplication.m:5064)
17  SwiftUI                         0x00000001af618f24 closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 164 (UIKitApp.swift:35)
18  SwiftUI                         0x00000001af546e08 runApp<A>(_:) + 252 (<compiler-generated>:0)
19  SwiftUI                         0x00000001af5280f4 static App.main() + 128 (App.swift:114)
20  Formatio                        0x000000010456f66c $main + 24 (<compiler-generated>:10)
21  Formatio                        0x000000010456f66c main + 36 (PopupView.swift:0)
22  dyld                            0x0000000104b2dda4 start + 520 (dyldMain.cpp:879)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002189f8e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002189f8e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002189f8e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001df2d54a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001df2d5ae4 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:119)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a77a6d30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:2646)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a77ab1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180 (CFRunLoop.c:3000)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a77bebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001a8fb1444 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001a8ff2e0c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001aa0accc4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 524 (UIEventFetcher.m:1167)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001a900141c __NSThread__start__ + 808 (NSThread.m:972)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002189f99ac _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:891)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002189f8e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002189f8e54 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000001c06770f5   x5: 0x000000016b89a380   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000500
    x8: 0x542ecb28520cf3c2   x9: 0x542ecb2956b4f642  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x000000000000000b  x13: 0x00000001a7b76a9f  x14: 0x00000001c067711b  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000104b80580  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000103  x21: 0x0000000104b80660  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000000000114
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000104b80660  x26: 0x0000000280668400  x27: 0x000000000000000f
   x28: 0x0000000002ffffff   fp: 0x000000016b89a2f0   lr: 0x00000002189ff3bc
    sp: 0x000000016b89a2d0   pc: 0x00000001df2dbb38 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault


Binary Images:
0x104564000 - 0x104727fff Formatio arm64  <d700ff8819213b64bb691fbd5a561386> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0147F52-1465-4998-A6F3-F0487C71B14F/Formatio.app/Formatio
0x1048e4000 - 0x104933fff FirebaseAuth arm64  <9f4c04eb8b0437ad907fd369ad59f814> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F0147F52-1465-4998-A6F3-F0487C71B14F/Formatio.app/Frameworks/FirebaseAuth.framework/FirebaseAuth
0x104b14000 - 0x104b6bfff dyld arm64e  <66e1fb2668f8379ba052eb8b8291b5e1> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1a749d000 - 0x1a74e2fff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <e3ea4f635d11342aaf199f58dbc8e259> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1a77a0000 - 0x1a7bf5fff CoreFoundation arm64e  <6b22dd8135853be6bc77ba19810ec0f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1a8f98000 - 0x1a92a2fff Foundation arm64e  <ee1abaf23d7137fb906715aa79528619> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1a9c1e000 - 0x1ab4bbfff UIKitCore arm64e  <137a95aada6d332cbc01e13bb9b6e317> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x1af3d9000 - 0x1b0470fff SwiftUI arm64e  <6ab6407f39eb3fb393d55e0c55af3a2d> /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
0x1b292b000 - 0x1b29aafff libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <86a1a24ace353769ba6960f28353281e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1c0552000 - 0x1c058efff libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <f6368be9109b3405b282624040529afd> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1c0662000 - 0x1c0679fff libc++abi.dylib arm64e  <d00067b20a7a3cb9b4d407b160da261b> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1c3928000 - 0x1c3930fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <a094e7b51d4037c5902756d86988ec4b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1df2d4000 - 0x1df309fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <9ab02ad0348c30cb99f40979c2d47515> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x2189f8000 - 0x218a03fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <a8989ffb141439dca1a81534f21923fe> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x21cf8f000 - 0x21cf93fff _AuthenticationServices_SwiftUI arm64e  <6dd58c3d8a82381bb089ae6d253567f5> /System/Library/Frameworks/_AuthenticationServices_SwiftUI.framework/_AuthenticationServices_SwiftUI

EOF
```

PodFile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Formatio' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Formatio

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  
  target 'FormatioTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'FormatioUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Thanks a lot for any assistance

Comment: which is line 91

Comment: This one: „Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in“

Comment: Start commenting put stuff I. That closure. You will likely find the issue

Comment: I commented out line 91 entirely and it fixed the crash. That means that line 91 causes the crash. Do you have any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Comment out the stuff inside the closure. My guess is that it will have todo with the login method you have in there. No way to help more specifically

Comment: I tried that already, but it didn‘t help. The app still crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue! I didn‘t check that I was not calling `FirebaseApp.configure()`. . When I made sure I was calling it, it worked without a problem.